# If I can download a file using browser, I should be able to do it from .NET code, right?

Tags: c#, http, download, webclient

Asked this on Salesforce stackexchange, posting here for broader audience.
My goal is to export Salesforce.com report. From a browser it works just fine, if I'm logged in and paste the following URL to my browser's address bar, the file gets downloaded:
"https://na9.salesforce.com/00OE0000001L8cUMAS/?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=CSV"

However, I need to export a bunch of reports from my .NET app. So using Analitics API I'm able to get the report ID that I need. Then I build the same url:

```
"https://na9.salesforce.com/00OE0000001L8cUMAS/?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=CSV"
```

Then I tried to do the following:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();               
wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + sForceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;                                
wc.DownloadFile(URL, Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), "report.csv"));
```

But this saves not the report but the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<script>
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00OE0000001L8cUMAS%2F%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3DCSV%26enc%3DUTF-8'); }  else 
if (window.location.replace){ 
window.location.replace('https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00OE0000001L8cUMAS%2F%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3DCSV%26enc%3DUTF-8');
} else {;
window.location.href ='https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00OE0000001L8cUMAS%2F%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3DCSV%26enc%3DUTF-8';
} 
</script>

</head>


</html>



<!--
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
...................................................................................................
-->
```

Looks like some redirection javascript, so I tried to do WebClient.DownloadFile, passing this redirection url:

```
string URL = "https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2F00OE0000001L8cUMAS%2F%3Fexport%3D1%26xf%3DCSV%26enc%3DUTF-8";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();               
wc.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + sForceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;                                
wc.DownloadFile(URL, Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), "report.csv"));
```

But this just returns the standard salesforce login screen saying that I need to log in. (although, I'm always passing an active sessionId in the header).
I don't believe there's no way to programmatically export a report, if I can do it in browser, I should be able to do it from code, I'm just missing something basic... Should sessionId be passed differently?

Comment: Yes. Use Fiddler and compare requests. Update your post with details when you figure out what the difference is (if you need details on how to set particular headers or like).

Comment: When I launch Fiddler, log in to Salesforce, then clear the Fiddler window, and enter the following url in the browser: https://na9.salesforce.com/00OE0000001L8cU?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=CSV, the browser downloads the file and in fiddler there's nothing. Like nothing at all.

Comment: That is strange... You saying you see traffic decrypted for any other HTTPS site but not this one? I don't know than (and clearly will not be able to suggest anything), sorry.

Comment: It is decrypted for this site, when I log in and browse around - there's a boatload of traffic going on, and it's to a bunch of different urls with lots of info in the headers. It's just when I tried to delete all the sessions and try just the url I'm interested in - no sessions showed up in Fiddler. Probably because it used an existing session which I have removed from the screen...
Anyways, the traffic for this site is too complicated to try to reproduce it in code.